# Disable QML console.log() messages

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

We are tunning the final release of our application, and we successfully disable the debug messages in c++.

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release):{
    message(Building in release mode. We deactivate the logs.)
    DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
} else {
    message(Building in debug mode.)
}
```

But, our QML javascript console.log() functions are still logging the information.

I also found [this source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#log) that clearly states: 
***The output is generated using the qDebug, qWarning, qCritical methods in C++ (see also Debugging Techniques).***

What doesnt make much sense to me, since Im already ignoring all the qDebugs()

So, the question is: 
**How to ignore all the console.log() ?**

I just think it should be an easy task, similar to the qDebug() messages.

For any further information, please leave a comment.

Note: I know that the link is for Qt 5., but im using Qt 4.8.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code for disabling console.log()

Comment: I saw that post, but I think is using to much resources for something that should be easily implemented. AFAIK, with the QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT Im pretty sure it literally removes the code, since the size of my app is reduced. I was expecting any similar macro. Thanks any way! :)

Answer (score 1):

If `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` successfully disables output from within Qt code, it should do the same for the [C++ functions](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquick1.git/tree/src/declarative/qml/qdeclarativeengine.cpp#n1907) that implement `console.log()`. However, I believe that those feature macros are deliberately not auto-tested (too many macros, too few hardware resources to test them on), so any bug report would be closed, and you'd be encouraged to submit a patch yourself.

Another solution might be to use [`qInstallMessageHandler()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler), as mentioned in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058456/suppress-qdebug-when-using-qtestlib) question.

---

Unfortunately this doesn't help you, but in Qt 5, it's enough to disable the [logging rule](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/qml/qml/v8/qqmlbuiltinfunctions.cpp?h=5.6#n1416) with the [`QT_LOGGING_RULES`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#configuring-categories) environment variable:

```
QT_LOGGING_RULES=qml=false
```

Comment: Hi! That was one of my possible solutions. I have successfully testested and I know it can work, but as I said before, i think is using to many resources (at the end, is a function calling other function). I was expecting a macro that will disable/remove the comments as QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT. I will wait to see if other answers provide more info, if not I will accept this as the answer. +1 for the deep explanation of how is handle in qt project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for a final release:

```
qputenv("QT_LOGGING_RULES", QByteArray("*.debug=false;qml=false"));
```